# comparing two files using python to get a matrix

Tags: python

I want to compare the contents of two files and then get a matrix, whereby matches are scored "1" and no matches scored "0". For example aer23 in file1.txt is used to search against all the elements in file2.txt, and the matches/no matches are recorded column-wise. So that in the in the output, the contents of file1.txt become the rows and the contents of file2.txt becomes the column

file1.txt:

```
aer23
aub1
fer4
qty1
sap89
xty32
```

file2.txt:

```
fer4
xty32
aer23
aub1
sap89
qty1
```

Output:

```
       fer4 xty32   aer23   aub1    sap89   qty1    
aer23   0   0   1   0   0   0   
aub1    0   0   0   1   0   0
fer4    1   0   0   0   0   0
qty1    0   0   0   0   0   1
sap89   0   0   0   0   1   0
xty32   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

my code:

```
outfile=open("out.txt","w")

record=[]
for line in open("file2.txt","r"):
    record.append(line)
    for line in open("file2.txt","r"):
        if line==iter(record):
            outfile.write("1","\t")
        else:
        outfile.write("0","\t")
        next
```

How can make this code to work? Thanks

Comment: Do you want a real matrix (array of arrays) or just a formatted print?

Comment: Thanks! I want a real matrix

Comment: What were you expecting `line==iter(record)` to do? `iter(record)` gives you a list iterator; there's no way that can be equal to a string.

Comment: Also, you have a nested loop `for line in …` inside another loop that opens the same file and uses the same variable name. What's that supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you were trying to do is this:

```
outfile=open("out.txt","w")

# First you need to write the header row
outfile.write("\t")
for line2 in open("file2.txt","r"):
    outfile.write(line2.strip() + "\t")
outfile.write("\n")

# You never do anything useful with record, so don't build it
#record=[]

# Open file1 and file2, not file2 and file2, and don't reuse the name line
for line1 in open("file1.txt","r"):
    # You need also need to write the header column
    outfile.write(line1.strip() + "\t")
    #record.append(line)
    for line2 in open("file2.txt","r"):
        # Don't try to compare the string to a list iterator, compare it
        # to the string from the other file.
        if line1==line2:
            # You can't pass write multiple arguments like print, just
            # put the two strings together
            outfile.write("1\t")
        else:
            # Indentation matters in Python
            outfile.write("0\t")
        # next is a function that gets the next value from an iterator;
        # just referring to that function by name doesn't do anything
        #next
    # Don't forget to end each line
    outfile.write("\n")

# You should always close files, but _especially_ writable files
outfile.close()
```

This can be improved a whole lot, but this should be the simplest set of changes that gets you close to where you want to be.

Rather than show you all the changes you could make one by one, let me show you how I'd write it, and you can look up all the functions in the help:

```
import csv
with open('file2.txt') as file2:
    columns = [line.strip() for line in file2]
with open('file1.txt') as file1, open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow([''] + columns)
    for line in file1:
        row = line.strip()
        writer.writerow([row] + [1 if row==column else 0 for column in columns])
```

Comment: Hi abarnet. Thanks a lot for explanations and codes. I understand python syntax better now. The second code worked perfectly! The first code missed scoring "1" for lines qti1 and xty32. Can you please explain why I would need "outfile.write("\t")" to write a header in the first code

Comment: @user27976: Look at your desired output. The first row has a blank first column before the `fer4` column. That means you have to write a tab before writing `fer4`.